# Go Tour basics #13: how come there's no overflow?

Tags: variables, types, go

In the Go Tour [basics, slice #13](http://tour.golang.org/#13), the following is presented:

```
MaxInt uint64     = 1<<64 - 1
```

It evaluates correctly as seen when the example gets run; I just can't seem to understand why.

`unit64` is the biggest container for an `int` in Go as far as I understand.

At the same time `1<<64` evaluates to an exception when used in an expression (such as in `fmt.Printf(1<<64)`) - that is, it's not `0` as in several other programming languages.

Still, when used on the right side of the assignment operator it evaluates fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, [slide #15](http://tour.golang.org/#15) seems to explain it: it's a constant and as such "does not have limited size" (not to 64 bits anyway).  I feel it strange but it's OK for an explanation.

Comment: I think what that means in practice is that if you have something of the form `const a T = b`, where T is a type, the expression `b` gets fully evaluated in that "no-size-limit" environment before they take the resulting value and try sticking it into the constant. Thus, `const MaxInt uint64 = 1<<64 - 1` evaluates first to `const MaxInt uint64 = 18446744073709551615`, which doesn't have any overflow.

Comment: In few words; the constant is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: In few words: all constants are evaluated at compile time using a special type that is *not* used at run time.

Comment: dont get mixed up, this has little to do with the `const` keyword. This is an `untyped constant value`. Read at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations `If a type is present, each variable is given that type. Otherwise, each variable is given the type of the corresponding initialization value in the assignment. If that value is an untyped constant, it is first implicitly converted to its default type;` and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants

Comment: I think you meant slide #16 https://tour.golang.org/basics/16